# Print message using SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server

I have two dates in SQL Server - `[O/R COMPLETE DATE]` and `[O/R SHIP BY]`. I want to check if `[O/R COMPLETE DATE]` is later than `[O/R SHIP BY]` and if so, I want to display a message saying `Overwrite shipBy date must be later than Overwrite Completed date`.

Is it something possible?

Comment: At which point you want such message?.I mean while inserting or upadating the record?? Can you describe your requirement in more deatil??

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN [O/R COMPLETE DATE] > [O/R COMPLETE DATE] THEN 'Overwrite shipBy date must be later than Overwite Completed date' ELSE NULL END AS Message`?

Comment: This feels like something that should be done in the application that is interacting with your databse before sending the data as part of data validation. Not something that should be done in the database itself.

Comment: You could also consider throwing an error rather than just returning a message string, which is sort of what this more sounds like to me. The trigger can then roll back parent transaction if it fails.

Comment: SQL Server triggers work *in the background* - the don't have any access to any UI, so they really cannot print messages or anything like that...

Comment: You should use a check constraint for this not a trigger. The application can catch the constraint violation though best that it doesn't send those values in the first place assuming that it always has access to both values.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
    CREATE TABLE OVERWRITE
        (OVERWRITEID int
        ,[O/R COMPLETE DATE] date
        ,[O/R SHIP BY] date
        ,[SHIP INSTRUCTIONS] AS 
            CASE WHEN [O/R COMPLETE DATE] > [O/R SHIP BY] 
                 THEN 'Overwrite shipBy date must be later than Overwrite Completed date' 
              ELSE 
                'Overwrite shipBy date and Overwrite Completed dates are valid' 
            END
        )


    INSERT INTO OVERWRITE
    VALUES (1,'1/1/2017', '6/1/2017'), (2, '11/1/2017', '10/1/2017')

    SELECT *
    FROM OVERWRITE
```

Triggers are not designed for output; as suggested earlier it's advisable to have the client application send messages. First line of defense to bad data in the db is the front-end app.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f0d0/1